# How to return an NSNumber converted to NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c

With NSNumber being a class, I am trying to convert it to an NSInteger to do some computations. In NSLog, it shows that I am converting and doing the multiplication correct. However, when I got to return doubler as a regular NSInteger, I get "Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'NSNumber* ' is disallowed with ARC". Where am I going wrong and what do I do to make this correct?

```
- (NSNumber *) numberThatIsTwiceAsBigAsNumber:(NSNumber *)number {

NSInteger doubler = [number integerValue] * 2;
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)doubler);

return doubler;
}
```

EDIT: For those curious, this is how I solved it:

```
NSInteger unboxing = [number integerValue] * 2;
NSNumber *boxing = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:unboxing];

return boxing;
```

Comment: return `@(doubler);`.

Comment: Or, the old fashioned way, `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:doubler]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the number as NSNumber, not NSInteger. So, convert the NSInteger to NSNumber before returning.

```
return @(doubler);
```

Comment: So essentially, I am unboxing the NSNumber to do my calculations and I just needed to rebox it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @JonJungemann Yes, you are correct, because with -(NSNumber *) you are saying that you will return this type. Also, you can use a shortcut to return an NSNumber by using: return @(doubler)

Answer (score 1):

Change your return type to

```
- (NSInteger)
```

If you intend to continue to use it as such, or explicitly cast it.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry copy & paste